# Modest Branding with Chromeless Player

Tags: javascript, youtube, chromeless

I have built a chromeless player for several websites I run based on
the following logic:

1) I create a standard embed as a fallback in the event the chromeless
version won't load. This enables ios devices to see the video just
fine.
2) I reference a JS file that handles my player controls.  In that
file, I embed a swf object with:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?   
   modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", "ytplayer",
   "640", "360", "8", null, null, params);
```

The swf object I embed overwrites my original embed code. so
effectively if the device viewing the page can support flash,
chromeless is displayed.  If not, it isn't

3) Below this reference, I include the following JS to tell the swf
object which video to play:

```
enter code here
 function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
     myPlayer = document.getElementById('ytplayer');
     myPlayer.loadVideoById('My_VIDEO_ID', 0);
     myPlayer.mute();
 }
```

obviously, I replace My_VIDEO_ID with the id of the video i want it to
play.

Once this all runs, my video works great EXCEPT the modest branding
doesn't work.  I've tried this 6 ways from sunday and I have 2
theories.  1) youtube disables modestbranding with a chromeless player
or 2) the separation of the swf object and the loading of the video
breaks it.

Is there a way to pass the modest parameter in the function call?
Are both theories wrong? :)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No 'modest branding' feature is available for the Chromeless player unfortunately. You can kinda see why as with no chrome or watermark there would be no sign this video belongs to YouTube. There is a [discussion on the topic here](http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/38f54a7e562b55e5).